# Thread without period or delay

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I always using TimerTask or ScheduledExecutorService, but we always need to enter period and delay.
Does it exist in Java way to run something in thread only once without delay (exept AsyncTask) ?

Comment: try IntentService

Comment: In Java8 or newer, you can use [`java.util.concurrent.CompletableFutre.supplyAsync(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //your code
    }
}).start();
```